# Can a wildshaped Druid proxy a touch spell through its familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, druid, familiars, wild-shape

A Druid in wild shape

> ... can’t cast spells ...

But, Find Familiar allows

> ... your familiar [to] deliver [a touch spell] **as if it had cast the spell**.

---

Does specific beat general here, and allow a Druid to cast touch spells while Wild Shaped?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### No

The rather key part of the *find familiar* is just before the bit you quoted (emphasis mine):

> *when you cast a spell* with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell

*Find familiar* allows the familiar to deliver a spell, but only a spell you cast. The spell simply activates when the familiar touches the target. Since you outright can't cast spells in wild shape (until you get the feature undoing that limitation at 18th level) you can't cast a spell for your familiar to deliver either.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation about invisible familiars has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139349/discussion-on-answer-by-someone-evil-can-a-wildshaped-druid-proxy-a-touch-spell). Feel free to continue it there.